# ClearCase issue two files pointing to the same resource

Tags: path, duplicates, clearcase

We have multiple projects in a given ClearCase view.  Somehow, we now have a handful of files that are pointing to the same resource in two different projects.

We had a `JavaTestProject` that was put in ClearCase as a sample project.

The code was used as a model to create a new project: `JavaLiveProject`.

For a few pieces of code with the same name, ClearCase has pointed the `JavaTestProject` to the `JavaLiveProject` file with the same name.

Using ClearCase Explorer, the View Path for `JavaTestProject/MyJavaProgram.java` looks like it belongs to `JavaTestProject`.
However, if you use the Properties of `Element` option, the full path is pointing to `JavaLiveProject/MyJavaProgram.java`.

If you check out and edit the file in either project, you are really editing `JavaLiveProject/myJavaProgram.java`.

We are not certain how this happened (we do not see any symlinks in ClearCase Explorer).
However, we would like to make it so that `JavaTestProject/myJavaProgram.java` does not affect `JavaLiveProject/MyJavaProgram.java`.

There are other instances where the code has the same name (`MySampleProgram.java` for instance) where this did not happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are we talking abut base ClearCase? or UCM project?

Comment: This is a ClearCase issue (integrated with Eclipse for Java projects).

Comment: Ok then, see my answer below: time to make `cleartool` talk (the CLI for ClearCase: Command-Line Interface)

Comment: Here is the descr for JavaLiveProject: version "MyJavaProgram.java@@\main\<<view>>\3" created 2012-05-23T16:18:25-04:00 by <<name of person>> Element Protection: User : ABC : r-- Group: DEF : r-- Other: : r-- element type: text_file predecessor version: \main\<<vob/view>>\2 Labels: MY_LABEL

Comment: Looks legit. What about `JavaTestProject/MyJavaProgram.java` ?

Comment: The JavaTestProject version looks the same.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to troubleshoot that kind of situation is to leave the GUI aside for a moment, and see what the command-line interface returns:

In a DOS session, go to your (snapshot I presume) view and type:

```
 cleartool ls
```

If there is a symlink (it shouldn't be since you didn't see it through the GUI, but I am just checking there), it would be displayed as:

```
JavaTestProject/MyJavaProgram.java --> C:\path\to\JavaLiveProject/MyJavaProgram.java
```

If not, check if there is some kind of OS-based symlink (like a [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx))

A cleartool descr -l of both "`JavaTestProject/MyJavaProgram.java`" and "`JavaLiveProject/MyJavaProgram.java`" can help troubleshoot the issue too.

Comment: cleartool ls outputs look the same as well.  The weird part is that there are other files in the same directory where this issue did not happen.  It is just with a handful of files.

Comment: @Ruminator then it might be an Eclipse issue, which somehow links (import) one `MyJavaProgram.java` into another.

Comment: I would agree that it is an Eclipse issue if I didn't see the same information in ClearCase Explorer.  It's kind of a mystery.  It is tempting to just make a backup copy and delete what is in ClearCase and re-add it.

Comment: @Ruminator that is one solution, the other would be to re-make first the Eclipse project (before modifying the ClearCase content)

Answer (score 0):

After working with ClearCase support (internal, not official), the reason that the files were pointing to the same resource could not be determined.  However, removing the files from the `JavaTestProject` seems to have cleared up the issue (it did not delete the files in `JavaLiveProject`).

I did make backup copies before deleting files from ClearClase, just in case.